# Template- and manifest-based Code Generation for Java

Tags: java, code-generation

I am building a heavily plugin-based application. The plugins communicate via a shared message bus. For several obvious reasons, including assurance of type safety, I end up writing code similar to this:

```
public class OtherPluginController {
    ...
    public void doSomething(int intParam, String stringParam) {
        Command cmd = new Command();
        cmd.target = "OtherPlugin";
        cmd.name = "doSomething";
        cmd.params.put("intParam", intParam);
        cmd.params.put("stringParam", stringParam);

        MessageBus.emit(cmd);
    }
    ...
}
```

For the sake of extensibility and maintainability it now would be great to create those controllers from some kind of manifest file, for the example above, and using XML, something like

```
<Plugin name="OtherPlugin">
    ...
    <Command name="doSomething">
        <Parameter name="intParam" type="int"/>
        <Parameter name="stringParam" type="String"/>
    </Command>
    ...
</Plugin>
```

Although there are plenty of template-based frameworks, most of them seem to target much different use cases. Is there a framework I missed? If not, is there a framework I could at least abuse for this kind of things?

Comment: Have you tried [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) to define your messages?

Comment: protobuf is a framework for serialization issues. Even if I would want to use serialized byte streams on my message bus, instead of POJOs, protobuf would not help me with the issue of manually assigning a method's name and parameters to a message object.

Comment: protobuf contains a code generator that writes the message POJOs for you.

Comment: To be clear: I do not want to automatically generate different versions of the `Command` object shown in the first snippet, I want to generate the first code snippet itself. And as far as I see it, protobuf isn't capable of that.

Comment: You can write your own code generators with Xtext. http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#TutorialCodeGeneration . Have a look. Maybe it fits your needs.

Comment: Xtext was a great hint. What bothered me was the need to define the DSL on my own and that Xtext is a very specific dependency. Both thoughts lead me to XSLT. So although I probably won't use Xtext, you helped me a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research I find that, if the "manifest" is provided in XML, the best and simplest approach seems to be [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). Given a manifest file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="PluginControllerTemplate.xsl"?>
<Plugin name="OtherPlugin">
    <Command name="doSomething">
        <Parameter name="intParam" type="int"/>
        <Parameter name="stringParam" type="String"/>
    </Command>
    <Command name="doSomethingElse"/>
</Plugin>
```

And an XSL-file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="Plugin" xml:space="preserve">
public class <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>Controller {
        <xsl:for-each select="Command">
    public void <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>(<xsl:for-each select="Parameter"><xsl:value-of select="@type"/> <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if></xsl:for-each>) {

    }       
        </xsl:for-each>
}
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output would be

```
public class OtherPluginController {

    public void doSomething(int intParam, String stringParam) {

    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {

    }

}
```

The main advantages of using XSLT are, that you don't need to define your own syntax and/or parser for your definition language and, as it works with any browser, it can be used without any additional setup. However, there are still ways to integrate XSLT into eclipse, if you want the code generation as part of your IDE.